# How can I strip several old commits but keep all the other commits unchanged in a git?

Tags: git

Suppose the structure of the commits is like the one below:

```
                 B'---C'           X'
                /      \          / \
           A---B---C---D---...---X---Y---Z(master)
```

And now I need to strip all the commits between A and X,

```
                         X'
                        / \
                   A---X---Y---Z
```

AFAIK, there are at least 2 way to achieve this:

- git rebase -i  A
- git branch -f new_branch A; git rebase --onto master X

But there are always some conflicts that I need to manually handle.

Since I only would like to purge all the commits after *A* and before *X* and I don't need to change any git tracking results after each commit(for instance, the newly generated commits X share the same contents as the old X commit), is there an easier way to do so?

Comment: if you want to strip all the commits between `A` and  `Y` then what do you want `X` and `x'` to be? would you prefer `A---Y---Z`?

Comment: @hus787 Sorry for the typo, it should be between A and X.

Comment: I'm assuming you want the stripped commits removed, not squashed right?

Comment: @Ajedi32 Yeah, I hope to keep the commit log clean and I am sure some of the old commits are no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This solution will squash the commits you want to "strip" into X, so that the new X commit and all following commits have their files in the exact same state that they are now. If this isn't what you wanted, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17215044/1157054).

---

```
git checkout -b temp A
git merge X --squash
git commit -C X # Create new x commit
git checkout master
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto temp X # Rebase onto new X commit (should produce no conflicts)
git -d temp
```

Comment: But there are conflicts when rebasing(I don't know why, maybe due to the submodules).

Comment: That's weird. The new X commit should have the exact same contents as the old one so there shouldn't be any conflicts. What files are the conflicts showing up in? Can you run a `git diff temp X` to ensure that there really is no difference between X and temp?

Comment: Oh, and try the rebase with the `--preserve-merges` option (see my edit above).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like:

```
git checkout -b new_X X
git rebase -i A # set everything to 'squash'
git checkout master
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto new_X X
```

This hopefully should keep commit changes the same, so there would be conflicts. If this fails, I would probably resort to low-level commands like `git commit-tree` and some script to create the new structure from original trees.

Comment: Conflicts occurred when `git rebase -i A` was processed.

Comment: Oh :/ then instead of the first rebase, look up X's tree id using `git cat-file commit X`, and make new_X commit directly with `git commit-tree` (adding A as parent).

Comment: Would you please write with more details? I haven't used `git commit-tree` before and I am afraid that I cannot revert back once I make a mistake:-)

Comment: Wait, how can you get conflicts when squashing commits? That doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: @HongxuChen: `git commit-tree` makes a new commit with given state of your tree and parents (see its man page). It does not destroy anything, so you should be pretty safe (similarly to rebases) by simply doing `git branch master-backup master` and returning to it if you don't like your results.

Comment: @che Is `git commit-tree` supposed to be rather slow? I type something like `git commit-tree X_tree_ID`(X has only one parent) but there is no response yet after about 20 min.

Comment: @HongxuChen: It's supposed to be almost instant, but it expects commit message on standard input. See `man git-commit-tree`; one way to run it is `echo 'this used to be X' | git commit-tree ...`.

Comment: @che I don't know why it sucks for me and I finally gave up. Maybe some days later I'll try and confirm your reply. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: This solution will *remove* the old commits (including any changes made in them) from the repository. This aparently isn't what the op was asking but I'll leave the answer here anyway for future readers.

---

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto A X~
```

I can't guarantee there won't be conflicts, but if you do run into any you can resolve them manually, `git add` the files with the conflicts, and then type `git rebase --continue`.

Alternately, you could force `git rebase` to automatically resolve any conflicts by applying the more recent changes over the top of any conflicting changes made in A (or before):

```
git checkout master
git branch backup # Just to be safe
git rebase -s theirs --onto A X~
git branch -D backup # When you're sure master has everything you need
```

Comment: But `git add` would cause the `both modified` files containing too many "<<<","===",">>>" and I still need to manually merge them?

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to do the merging manually if you get conflicts. I'm not really sure how that could be avoided though.

Is there something about the contents of these commits that makes you believe it should be possible to do the rebase without conflicts?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the meaning of your last sentence:-<

Comment: I'm just a bit confused about why you seem to believe it's possible to remove those commits without encountering any merge conflicts. Basically, I don't understand the last paragraph in your question. Could you elaborate on that a little?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I'm not familiar with git, and I don't know whether it is possible. I hope the commits between A and X are `cut`, and all the other commits(A, X and those after X) remain unchanged.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. Commits in git are expressed as a list of changes, so when you were talking about the commit's contents I thought you were talking about the diff. What you really meant by "contents" though was state of the files in the repo after that commit was applied. (Right?)

In that case, @che's answer is actually a bit closer to what you were looking for.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Commits in git store state of all your files ("a tree") and links to parent commits. There's no concept of changes on object level.

Comment: @che Really? That wasn't how I understood it. Do you have a link to some place that explains this further?

Comment: @Ajedi32: Sure: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-Objects#Commit-Objects

Comment: @che Ah, that's a very interesting read. Conceptually I still think calling a commit a list of changes is a better abstraction, but it's definitely a good thing to understand that, under the hood, that's not really the case.